# Difference between channel.addPeer() and channel.joinPeer()

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am studying **Hyperledger Fabric** and running samples from the Hyperledger fabric samples . 
I have run th **BYFN** network http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/build_network.html

And i am able to access the peers , invoke and query chaincode using the Fabric Java SDK .

I add the peers to the channel using channel.addPeer() function and initilaize.

There is also a method joinPeer() in channel class .

I want to know the difference between **channel.addPeer()** and **channel.joinPeer()**

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the source code? [Channel.java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdk/Channel.java)

Comment: i did . in joinPeer() it says peer is 'added' with roles . I am not able to get the clear picture though .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you join peers you actually update the 'channel'.
But, when you add peers, you are basically just updating a local copy of the 'channel object', and assume that the peers had already 'joined'.

If you would look at the 'joinPeer' method, you would see that it calls 'addPeer', and it gets the genesis block from a random orderer.
On the other hand addPeer updates some internal maps.

With enough mental gymnastics it starts to make sense.

Source code:
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/f11f197852d4596d2ab6e4c88eb4fe861d3765c4/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdk/Channel.java#L837